# How to get values from a column with format of dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have adata frame with this column and this information

```
slice_info                                 time                             
----------------------------------------- -----
{'gaming': 2, 'main': 92, 'working': 9}   2021-09-11 00:04:00
{'gaming': 4, 'main': 78, 'working': 10}  2021-09-11 00:04:00
.....
```

How can I get the values that belong to gaming and the sum this 2 and 4 value?

Comment: Does `df['slice_info'].str.get('gaming').sum()` work?

Answer (score 0):

You could just [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) a function to retrieve the value from the dictionary and then sum those values:

```
df["slice_info"].apply(lambda entry: entry["gaming"]).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse and convert:

```py
import json

rows = []

for line in data.splitlines()[2:]:
    rows.append(json.loads(line.split('}')[0].replace("'", '"') + "}"))

print(rows[0]["gaming"])  # 2
```